# WatchKit background processing

Tags: objective-c, background, watchkit

It may very well be a design issue but i am trying to build a watchOs 2 app that is essence a specialised timer that counts down to a specific time according to some parameters that user dials in.

Then I start a NSTimer to count down to this specified time the problem is that when the watch goes dark the timer suspends is there any way to stop this from happening or is there an alternative method.

Regards Christian

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You don't need to sign your questions (in fact, it's frowned upon).  Your avatar and username are already added to the bottom of the question.

Answer (score 0):

Use a local notification on the phone.

Comment: Just to be clear -- I believe this is the only possible way for a non-Apple app to do this. Download "Due" from the AppStore -- it's, by far, the best timer app, and that's what it does.

Comment: I don't want the app to be dependent on the phone when I use the app I don't have the phone on me

Comment: I do not believe this is possible

Comment: Is there no way for the watch extention on the watch to set a LocalNotification ? Without having an iPhone involeved